Approach to Poisson distribution question
I'm trying to understand the Poisson distribution. I have a question: the number of emails I get in a weekday can be modeled by a Poisson distribution with an average of 0.2 emails per minute. What's the probability that I get one email in an interval of length 5 minutes?
Is the following approach correct?
Let $X$ be the number of emails received in a minute, which can be modeled by a Poisson distribution. Then, $P(X=1) = \frac{e^{-0.2}\cdot{0.2^1}}{1!}=e^{-0.2}\times{0.2}$
Then, the probability of receiving no emails in five minutes is simply $(e^{-0.2}\times{0.2})^5$

When computing probabilities of a Poisson-distributed random variable or process, a key insight is to express the intensity (also called the rate or mean) of events according to the total observation time over which you are interested in counting those events.
What I mean by this is that if you are told that there are on average $0.2$ emails per minute, but you want to know how many emails arrive in a $5$-minute interval, then the event rate has been specified using units of time that don't match the observation time:  the rate is specified in units of emails per minute, but the observation time is $5$ minutes.  So you must convert the rate units accordingly:
$$\frac{0.2 \text{ emails}}{\text{minute}} = \frac{1 \text{ email}}{5 \text{ minutes}}.$$
So on average, you should expect to see $1$ email in a $5$-minute time interval.  That is to say, the Poisson intensity for a $5$-minute interval is $$\lambda = 1 \text{ email per 5 minutes}.$$  But the arrivals are random, so the probability that you get exactly one email is
$$\Pr[X = 1] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^1}{1!} = e^{-1} \frac{1^1}{1!} = e^{-1} \approx 0.367879.$$
The probability of getting $0$ emails in $5$ minutes is
$$\Pr[X = 0] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^0}{0!} = e^{-1} \approx 0.367879.$$
This just happens to be equal to the probability of getting exactly one email.  The probability of getting at least one email in $5$ minutes is
$$\Pr[X \ge 1] = 1 - \Pr[X = 0] = 1 - e^{-1} \approx 0.632121.$$

For further understanding:

What is the probability of getting exactly $7$ emails in one hour?
What is the probability of getting no more than $4$ emails in half an hour?


Thank you very much!

It's important here that the sum of independent Poisson distributions is a Poisson distribution. For example, if you were given conversely that the distribution of emails every $5$ minutes is Poisson, it's not clear to me that you could infer that the distribution of emails every minute must also be Poisson (even assuming they are iid).
